# Find out the latest version of Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is there a programmatic source for checking what the latest version of Minecraft is?

For example a RSS feed or other URL from an official source that states the latest release version? Ideally without scraping HTML.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[mcupdate.tumblr.com](http://mcupdate.tumblr.com/), with which you can subscribe to with RSS, seems to reliably report the latest version as the newest post with the title **Minecraft `[x.x(.x)]`**.

**EDIT**

I'm slightly drunk, and feeling bashy, so here's a command that will return the latest version of Minecraft:

```
 curl -s http://mcupdate.tumblr.com/rss | egrep -o -e 'le>Minecraft [0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9]|le>Minecraft [0-9]\.[0-9]' | head -1 | egrep -o -e '[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9]|[0-9]\.[0-9]'
```

Comment: More specifically, http://mcupdate.tumblr.com/rss

Comment: Can I get one of those for windows batch?

Comment: @JeffreyLin No.